# override 'shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier' function throws error

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to prevent all segues if a certain condition is not met. This is how I have approached this problem:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    if condition == false {
        print("Segue wont occur")
        return false
    }
    else {
        print("Segue will occur")
    }

    return true
}
```

Though this solution seems to work for many people, I cannot compile, and I am thrown the error:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

The override function is located within the `UIViewController` superclass.

I am using Swift 4, and I have searched thoroughly for a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: “I am using Swift 4” no you aren’t. “and I have searched thoroughly for a solution” no you haven’t. That’s the problem. Look at the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformsegue Copy and paste! It’s `override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool`

Comment: An easy way to figure out yourself is to comment out the entire method, retype *shouldPerf* and use code completion.

Comment: @vadian thank you for that advice. I was stupid enough not to see that I had the ending wrong. Thank you for the time

Comment: @matt thank you for that answer. What do you mean when you say I am not using Swift 4?

Comment: I mean your code is Swift 1.

Comment: @matt if I’m not mistaken, Xcode 10 uses Swift 4.2. Are you talking about something else?

Comment: Yes, so YOU need to use Swift 4.2. `func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` is Swift 1 or 2.

Comment: @matt Okay, well I think we established that I mistakenly used a outdated function name. Doesn’t mean the rest of the code is Swift 1. I am programming in Swift 4.2, but a code snipped I used happened to be outdated and I didn’t realise. I think that’s where the confusion came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have gotten the method signature for [`shouldPerformSegue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformsegue) wrong.

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if condition == false {
        print("Segue wont occur")
        return false
    }
    else {
        print("Segue will occur")
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake and was stupid enough not to realise this.

Comment: When overriding methods, it is always better to let autocomplete do the job like @vadian has stated in his comment. No way of going wrong then.